# Get the URL in variable and then redirect with .htaccess

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, variables, cookies

I'm trying to get the recently entered URL because I will use it to make a query.

Let's say I have a website:

```
mysite.com
```

When someone visit my site with this address

```
mysite.com/thisisjustsometextcanbeanything
```

I want to use `.htaccess` to redirect from that address to `mysite.com`

But before it redirects I want to grab the  `mysite.com/thisisjustsometextcanbeanything` and store it in a variable so I can use it later.

I have studied `document.referrer` with help from JavaScript and some stuff with PHP. I think the right way is to store the value with help of cookies but don't know how to do it.

If it's unclear just ask your question and I will answer them.

Thanks

Comment: In .htaccess write a rule to redirect from those URLS to `./route.php` and in this php file - `get` the url and using `header('location:..)` send him to `mysite.com`.

Comment: @Prasath K When editing a post, kindly take your time to fix all issues and not just a few. Particularly, SO isn't a text message, remove all smilies and slang. And don't add strange emphasis in bold letters that wasn't present in the original post. Thank you.

Comment: @Lundin didn't i fix everything ...?? Sorry if i missed any

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right way. You should first do the redirect and then parse the referrer in your php script. Referrer is accessed through the $_SERVER variable like this and it keeps the referring url of the user.

```
$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]
```

When you do redirects like this mysite.com/something, you should check if `something` does exists like a file, and if it does, don't do any redirects. This is done by using this lines before your rewriterules.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

As conditions to your .htaccess file. Wordpress are doing it this way.

That's it, try to do it alone and if you have any problems, write here again :).

Comment: I had lucky this time. Under the time I tried your ways I realized that I could use ErrorDocument 404 and get the redirect and still have the value up in the adressbar. Then I just needed to grab the part I wanted with this code. var url = window.location.pathname;
 var url = url.substring(8);